# How to redirect to another page from an if statement Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am creating a virtual waldo game where you must find the characters from the image.

I am trying to make it so that when the game ends and the if statement is run it goes to another page the displays gameover. I have tried multiple ways to solve this such as using history.push or Navigate from the react-router-dom library but i cannot figure out how to get it to work

```
const Game = (props) => {
    const handleClickOption = (e) => {
        if (whichTarget.current === e.target.textContent.toLowerCase()) {
            if (e.target.textContent === 'Waldo') {
                setWaldoStyle(true);
            }
            if (e.target.textContent === 'Odlaw') {
                setOdlawStyle(true);
            }
            if (e.target.textContent === 'Wizard') {
                setWizardStyle(true)
            }
            console.log(e.target.textContent + ' found');
            hit.current += 1

            console.log('this is hit' + hit.current);
            if (hit.current === 3) {
                //function to reset and end game
                console.log("running game over code");
                props.history.push('/gameover');
                console.log('gameover code after navigate');
            }
        }
        
        setRender(!render);
    }
    return (
        <div id="gamePage">
            <div id="stopwatch">{hour.current}:{minute.current}:{second.current}</div>
            <div id="gameBoard">
                <img id="gameBackground" src={gameBackground} alt="gameboard" onClick={handleClickTrue} onLoad={startTimer}></img>
                <div id="waldo" className="hitBox" onClick={handleClickOnTarget}></div>
                <div id="odlaw" className="hitBox" onClick={handleClickOnTarget}></div>
                <div id="wizard" className="hitBox" onClick={handleClickOnTarget}></div>
                <div id="popupContainer">
            </div>
                {render ? <Popup close={handleClickOption} coords={translate} colorWaldo={waldoStyle} colorOdlaw={odlawStyle} colorWizard={wizardStyle}/> : null}
            </div>
            <button onClick={stopTimer}>BREAK</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to redirect the user to another page if he lost you might use:

```
if (hit.current === 3) {
   //function to reset and end game
   console.log("running game over code");
   window.location = "./gameover";
   console.log('gameover code after navigate');
}
```

Comment: Thank you it finally worked, i saw this method before but for whatever reason didnt try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what error you received when using `props.history.push()`, I can only assume that the `history` prop was not passed to your component (and that might be because of how your router was set up).

In any case, using `window.location` means using the browser API directly & doing things outside of the React Router context. If you want to fully use this library but aren't sure how to access the `history` prop for navigation, you could always get it by using the `useHistory` [hook they provide](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory):

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```